# How can I add a bullet image to the top right side 3 times

Tags: html, css

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp2S3.png)

here's my codee [codepen](https://codepen.io/tankmagee/pen/rNqLJNm)`my link`

"I have tried it, but the image is still in one vertical line."

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.inner {
  padding-top: 20p x;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.container1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 1rem 80px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.skill-box1 {
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.skill-title1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.skill-title1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.skill-title1:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.img1 {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 45px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.img1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90px;
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
  border-radius: 45px 0 0 45px;
}

.skill-title1 h3 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.skill-icon1 {
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Kemampuan</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="skill-box1">
      <div class="skill-title1">
        <div class="img1">
          <img src="https://swimburger.net/media/ppnn3pcl/azure.png" class="skill-icon1">
        </div>
        <h3>MIKROTIK</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="skill-box1">
        <div class="skill-title1">
          <div class="img1">
            <img src="https://swimburger.net/media/ppnn3pcl/azure.png" class="skill-icon1">
          </div>
          <h3>MIKROTIK</h3>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and reduce your code into a [mre] and read [ask]

Comment: because your second `skill-box1` element is nested inside of your first `skill-box1` element. Formatting of the question shows the nesting....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing 2 closing  tags for `skill-box1`,
this should work:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Kemampuan</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="skill-box1">
                <div class="skill-title1">
                    <div class="img1">
                        <img src="https://swimburger.net/media/ppnn3pcl/azure.png" class="skill-icon1">
                    </div>
                    <h3>MIKROTIK</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="skill-box1">
                <div class="skill-title1">
                    <div class="img1">
                        <img src="https://swimburger.net/media/ppnn3pcl/azure.png" class="skill-icon1">
                    </div>
                    <h3>MIKROTIK</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful. I have tried it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have some unnecessary divs that could be causing some issues. Without knowing if you have anything planned for those, I might suggest removing them.

I [reworked your code](https://codepen.io/jhunnicutt/pen/eYPddym) a bit, and employed `display:flex` on the div containing the image and text. Using flex box, the div defaults to a row layout. Then I can use `align-items:center` to get everything to even out.

Answer (score 0):

**To remove the error in the HTML code, you need to close the first div tag with class container1 before opening the second div tag with class skill-box1**

the correct code is:

```
<div class="inner">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Kemampuan</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="skill-box1">
      <div class="skill-title1">
        <div class="img1">
          <img src="https://swimburger.net/media/ppnn3pcl/azure.png" class="skill-icon1">
        </div>
        <h3>MIKROTIK</h3>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- close the first skill-box1 div here -->
    <div class="skill-box1">
      <div class="skill-title1">
        <div class="img1">
          <img src="https://swimburger.net/media/ppnn3pcl/azure.png" class="skill-icon1">
        </div>
        <h3>MIKROTIK</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and try to use the comments in the code

**to add a bullet image to the top right side 3 times, you can use the CSS ::before or ::after pseudo-elements on a container element and position them accordingly**

so refer any article or youtube video to learn pseudo elements

and if you are facing error in the alignment of images try to use **FLEXBOX** it helps you to apply css easily

see a tutorial regarding it u will get your problem solved